# How to create a variable number of UIImageViews in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

My problem is that based on the number of groups a person has I want to dynamically create that many `UIImageView` and assign them to the view. I know how to create a single `UIImageView` and put it onto the view but how can I create a variable number of them since creating another with the same name seems to just overwrite the original? I tried sending the `UIImageView` into an Array but got an optional error.

```
            circleView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(125, y, 75, 75))
            y+=150
            circleView.image = UIImage(named:"circle.png")
            circleView.tag = i
            self.view.addSubview(circleView)
            circleArray[i] = circleView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you keep reusing the same circleView instance. When you add it to the array, you are just adding a reference to it. You then reinitialize it, which wipes it out. I also don't see where you are incrementing i. Try something like this:

```
var circleArray = Array<UIImageView>()
var y : CGFloat = 0.0
var i = 0
circleArray.append(UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(125, y, 75, 75)))
var circleView = circleArray[i]
circleView.image = UIImage(named:"circle.png")
circleView.tag = i
self.view.addSubview(circleView)

y+=150
i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `circleArray.append(circleView)`

Comment: Wow can't believe I made that mistake thanks for catching it!

Comment: Even with the correct syntax it seems to be throwing the same optional error. Any thoughts?